# How to align this view of android coding programmatically

Tags: android

[image]

How to align this view of android coding programmatically.This view very difficult my part please help me the image is given below...

Comment: What do you mean by align? This can be done using relativeLayout as a listView item if you mean that.

Comment: If you want someone to provide you with code to create this view I don't think you will get it. Make an attempt to write it and come back if you have specific problems. Good luck!

Comment: cannot design programmatically....

Answer (score 0):

First of all,it is Itinerary not Itenary.You can create a `ListView` for this.Create your `ListView` layout and `ListView` item `xml` and add data programmatically.

Comment: am already create a list view but cannot create a design programmatically.please help me..

Comment: Post your class file and xml.